# CodeIgniter/MySQL - select, where not equal to and like twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am having problems returning the correct records when using the following active record query in CodeIgniter:

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT fName, lName, userID 
                       FROM user 
                       WHERE userID !='$user_id'
                       AND fName LIKE '%$search_criteria%' 
                       OR lName LIKE '%$search_criteria%'");
```

The query searches the users table based on `$search_criteria`. `$user_id` is the ID of the logged in user so they don't appear in the search results.

If I search for the logged in users first name it doesn't return the logged in user in the search results, but it does return the logged in user if i search by their last name, which I don't understand why...

Comment: wrap conditions in "()" , like `userID !='$user_id' AND (fName LIKE '%$search_criteria%' OR lName LIKE '%$search_criteria%'')

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in the logic, you want to check user ID, and check for either first name OR last name... What I did here was look for userID AND fname or lname. The parens separate the criteria, allowing either fname or lname but always ID

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT fName, lName, userID 
                       FROM user 
                       WHERE userID !='$user_id'
                       AND (fName LIKE '%$search_criteria%' 
                       OR lName LIKE '%$search_criteria%'"));
```